# Is it possible to have conditional columns in a List/DataGrid in Admin on REST?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, admin-on-rest

If I apply a filter in a `List` component in Admin on REST, I want to only show the filtered column (`TextField`) once this specific filter is selected, because the filter is fuzzy and I want to see the different results at a glance. But when no filter is set, the column is supposed to be hidden.

I implemented it like this so far.

```
const ConditionalFilterTextField = (props) => {
    const show = ... // if filter is set in URL
    return (show) ? <TextField {...props} /> : null
}
```

...

```
<List {...props} filters={<MyFilter />}>
  <Datagrid>
    ...
    <ConditionalFilterTextField sortable={false} source="filter_field" label="My Label" />
    ...
  </Datagrid>
</List>
```

This does work in a way, but then again not really. It shows the label of the column and an empty space when I return `null` (when the filter is not set and the column is supposed to be hidden).

How can I control visibility of a TextField depending on whether a filter is set or not? How can I force a rerender of the List when I want to add a column?

---

Edit:

This is similar to your answer, @Gildas, but doesn't work for me. Some detail might be wrong?

*in itemList.js*

```
class ItemList extends Component {
  render() {
    const props = this.props
    // Find out if current filter is source of field.
    const filter = props.itemsFilters
    const showFieldA = (filter && filter.fieldA) ? true : false

    return <List {...props} filters={<ItemsFilter />} perPage={50}>
      <Datagrid>
        <ReferenceField sortable={false} source="id" reference="items" linkType="show">
          <TextField source="fieldB" />
        </ReferenceField>
        <TextField sortable={false} source="fieldC" />
        <TextField sortable={false} source="fieldD" />
        <DateField sortable={false} source="fieldE" />
        { (showFieldA === true) ? <TextField sortable={false} source="fieldA" /> : null }
        <ShowButton />
        <EditButton />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  }
}

const ItemsFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="FilterSearch" source="q" />
    <TextInput label="FilterA" source="fieldA" />
  </Filter>
)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    itemsFilters: state.admin.resources.items.list.params.filter
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemList)
```

...
*in App.js*

```
<Resource name="items" list={ItemList} show={ItemShow} edit={ItemEdit} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const MyList = (props) => {
    const show = ... // if filter is set in URL

    return (
        <List {...props} filters={<MyFilter />}>
            <Datagrid>
                ...
                {show ? <TextField {...props} /> : null}
                ...
            </Datagrid>
        </List>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! I tried this as well, but unless `show` is `true` from initial page load on, it won't show the column even though `show` eventually becomes `true`.

Comment: Can you post the full code of your List component ?

Comment: So, does it make a difference if I implement my own List component, as you propose?

Comment: No that's not what I meant, `MyList` here is just a name for your `ItemList`. I'll have to investigate a little in order to answer

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Do you think it's a bug or just not supposed to work like that?

Comment: Sorry, haven't got any time for that yet. Too much on my plate right now

Comment: The behavior seems to have changed in the recent version and it works now!  1.4.0 works: https://codesandbox.io/s/4qr8rp0j37; 1.3.3 doesn't work: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxv4o75rn5. (Try to filter the post list for “commentable” to toggle the “commentable” column.)